# Adding quotes to an json array and add attribute key with jq

Tags: json, jq

This below is my original json:

```
{
"type": "type1",
"name": "abc",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "district": "d1", "district_code": "101", "block_code": "1010070" }},
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "district": "d1", "district_code": "101", "block_code": "1010100" }}]
}
```

My expected result:

```
[
  {
    "Data": "{\"properties\":{\"district\":\"d1\",\"district_code\":\"101\",\"block_code\":\"1010070\"}}"
   },
  {
    "Data": "{\"properties\":{\"district\":\"d1\",\"district_code\":\"101\",\"block_code\":\"1010100\"}}"
  }
]
```

So far I am only able to add quotes by:

```
.features[] | del(.type) | tojson
```

which will only give me:

```
"{\"properties\":{\"district\":\"d1\",\"district_code\":\"101\",\"block_code\":\"1010070\"}}"
"{\"properties\":{\"district\":\"d1\",\"district_code\":\"101\",\"block_code\":\"1010100\"}}"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`jq`** approach:

```
jq '.features | map(del(.type) | {Data: tojson})' file.json
```

Or the same with *array* construction `[...]`:

```
jq '[.features[] | del(.type) | {Data: tojson}]' file.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "Data": "{\"properties\":{\"district\":\"d1\",\"district_code\":\"101\",\"block_code\":\"1010070\"}}"
  },
  {
    "Data": "{\"properties\":{\"district\":\"d1\",\"district_code\":\"101\",\"block_code\":\"1010100\"}}"
  }
]
```